# Android Eclipse debug on phone

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I don't want to debug my Android apps on emulator (Android Virtual Device) anymore. Instead, I want to debug it on my phone. My phone is LG Optimus L7 P700.
 I already have downloaded USB Driver for my phone from official LG support web site. On my AVD Manager: Google USB Driver is also installed.  Also, I ticked my Settings > Developer options-> USB debugging on my phone to be enabled. I connected my phone via USB cable, but I have problem now. When I run `adb devices` command on my command prompt as mentioned on tutorials I found on Google, my list of attached devices is empty, as u can see below in screenshoot. 
Here is screenshoot of my command prompt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhflH.jpg

Also when I go to My Computer->Manage, my phone have yellow exclamation point, I dont know why ? Here is screenshoot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7zVb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check your phone is rooted ,if your phone is rooted then use wifi adb application and connect to eclipse.
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wifi%20adb&hl=en

Comment: Sorry but I don't have wifi at home...

Comment: ok you can use another option dowload deploygate sdk from following website and implement into project ,see the following site \https://deploygate.com/docs/sdk

Comment: U dont understand me at all, my problem is that my device is NOT RECOGNIZED as u can see in screenshoot above. I can't do anything with my app project until my PC recognize my phone when I attach him...

Answer (score 0):

this is tricky sometimes. uninstall adb drivers through device manager and re-install them. uninstall all other adb drivers probably installed on your machine first before re-install. after installation connect your phone and choose driver-path manually. this is always the biggest pain for me with android development, I wasn`t able to connect one of my devices at all.